# Should a new node process be spawned for handling more than 100 requests?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, process

I'm building a website where a user can upload their CSV file which contains certain id's. My application will lookup those id's using AJAX requests. The amount of id's in the CSV file may be between 100 - 50000.

I'm wondering if it's a best practice to spawn a new node.js process to handle each such CSV because else the event loop will be full of thousands of such AJAX requests and responses. So if the user needs to trigger an AJAX request somewhere in the website for some small task (not related to the CSV) that request will be queued after potentially tens of thousands of other requests which will result in bad user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry. Nodejs can handle that much API requests.
If you're using pm2 to start processes, you can use `pm2 start <entry-file.js> -i max` to start the processes according to CPU cores you have.

To avoid bad user experience, you can immediately send user a response that your work is in progress and notify your user about completion of work later.

what's your thought ?